# Is there a todo-list /tasks widget that will sync with Google Tasks?

Tags: desktop-gadget, to-do

I'd like to be able to see an at-a-glance view of Google tasks on my desktop (XP). Has anyone found a Yahoo widget or Google gadget that will do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Desktop iCalendar](http://www.desksware.com/desktop-icalendar-lite.htm) and [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net) both can show Google Tasks on the desktop.

Comment: The link you have provided for Desktop iCalendar doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have found is to log into GMail, click tasks, then click arrow to popout which makes it a separate window.  In addition I use a Firefox extension called MinUI to trim down the window to a minimum. It is a stand-alone window on the desktop, but goes away if you close Firefox or leave GMail. I keep it open all the time even when I minimize other browser windows.